# Does XFBML work in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: html, facebook, internet-explorer-9, xfbml

I have a like box setup in my website using the following code as exampled by Facebook.

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/platform" width="292" show_faces="true" stream="true" header="true"></fb:like-box>
```

It works in all browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera, Firefox, IE7, IE8) but not IE9. On inspecting the code it still reads the same as above, whereas the others get replaced with an iFrame.

I have also tried adding the following line to the html element, although this did not help.

```
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

The iframe version of the like box does however work, but XFBML is more desired.

Comment: Having the same problem. I integrated FB Connect with my site over a year ago with XFBML... all good till IE9 came out :( I've noticed XFBML is now considered legacy.

Comment: Yep... I guess a lot of people haven't realised yet. I still haven't found a solution. Will post one here if I do. Still if its considered legacy... maybe I should just use the iFrame version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why it is not working in IE9, but changing the document mode to IE8 will make it work -you can do that by adding this to the head section

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Ah yes, that's got it going. Does this however mean that IE9 loses it's HTML5 functionality?

Comment: @diggersworld: yes, unfortunately.

Comment: Not an ideal solution then really. :/

Answer (score 3):

You can add facebook namespaces to the head of your HTML. Just make sure you format correctly.

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
    <body>
        <!-- My super great XFBML like button -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I found the solution for me:
I'm using blogger template which by default contain this tag:

```
<meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
```

I deleted it and everything is working good.